# Is it possible to alias nil in Golang

Tags: go

While organizing my projects, I observe nil comparisons in many places. I wish to replace `nil` with `NULL` or `Null`. I respect Golang specs, but I am curious if we can do this.

I already did it for `interface{}` , `context.Context` as follows.

```
type CON = context.Context 
type Any = interface{}
```

Comment: This not only is just impossible it also is a terrible idea.

Comment: thanks @Volker .. understood. I am curious at the edges

Comment: This issue isn't specifically about gofmt, but you can see from this [quote](https://youtu.be/PAAkCSZUG1c?t=524) about gofmt from Rob Pike, that visual uniformity is encoded into the ethos of Go code. Or in other words, it's actually considered *valuable* to *prevent* programmers from making these kinds of cosmetic choices (`nil` vs `NULL`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. What you show there are type aliases. `nil` is not a type. It is a value of a wide range of different types. You may hope that you can make a constant with a value of `nil`, similar to how you can make a constant of value `0`, but this is explicitly disallowed by the compiler:

```golang
const NULL = nil
```

Error: `const initializer cannot be nil`

According to the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants):

> There are boolean constants, rune constants, integer constants, floating-point constants, complex constants, and string constants.

None of these types can have a `nil` value, therefore a `nil` constant is not possible.

You might also try to make a variable which holds the value `nil`, but you'll find the problem that it doesn't work if you don't declare the type of the variable:

```golang
var NULL = nil
```

Error: `use of untyped nil`

You can make it legal by adding a `nil`able type to the variable, but then it will no longer be very useful as it will only be comparable to that specific type.